# Проблемы вызова переменной с помощью модуля ctypes

Tags: python, dll, pycharm, ctypes

Подключил dll программа корректно ее читает,

```
datserdll = ctypes.CDLL("C:\I_NP_10\Serv1.dll")
datserdll.func_ret_int.restype = ctypes.c_int
datserdll.func_ret_int.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ]
LF = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(datserdll, "LF")
print('ret LF: ', LF.value)
```

но при попытке выдает ошибку

```
File "C:\I_NP_10\app_24_project\DLLread.py", line 5, in <module>
  datserdll.func_ret_int.restype = ctypes.c_int
File "C:\Python32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
  func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "C:\Python32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
  func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'func_ret_int' not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Прошу подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: Ошибка буквально говорит, что в dll нет такой функции. Нужно смотреть какие функции экспортирует dll файл (возможно имена видоизменены, или еще что-то).

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вообще указывать restype учитывая что

> By default functions are assumed to return the C int type

Ну и далее

> return types can be specified by setting the restype attribute of the **function object**.

Т.е.

```
datserdll = ctypes.CDLL("C:\I_NP_10\Serv1.dll")
my_func = datserdll.func_ret_int
my_func.restype = ctypes.c_int
```